# convert non serializable object to string in C#

Tags: c#, xml, string

I have an object (`User`) which is not marked as `[Serializable()]`.

I need to convert the entire object (including child objects) to string.

This is an actual need to convert the object from a third party tool response which is not marked as `[Serializable()]`.

How can i convert an entire C# object to string/xml of the above scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `XmlSerializer` does not need the `Serializable` attribute, but it can only serialize public members.

Best Regards
Oliver Hanappi

---

Edit: You can create your own adapter class, which implements the [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) interface and represents one User object which your adapter gets when constructed.

Comment: How can i get the Non-public members to string/xml? The third party tool has a set of methods from which i can get the values. I need to get the values from each of the methods or otherwise the non-public members value

Comment: You could implement the IXmlSerializable interface on an adapter class (see edit).

Answer (score 1):

If JSON satisfies your needs, you can try [JsonExSerializer](http://code.google.com/p/jsonexserializer/) as it does not need any attributes to decorate targeted objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection to find all of the members that you are interested in e.g. public properties and/or private fields and then construct an xml document as you go.

That way would could keep the code generic and as custom as you like. :)

However, remember that reflection can be a very slow process at runtime. :(